# Controller Inheritance in Laravel 5.6

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, relationship, laravel-5.6

I have three Table users, Profiles, and Documents. I'm Create single user Profile page using relationship now i want to fetch data or Documents related to user profile. every Single user Have Many Documents. i don't know to fetch all Document related to user.

```
public function show(User $client)
{
    return view('admin.profile', compact('client'));
}
```

it's single profile fetch function.

Comment: Do you have your documents relationship set up in your `User` model?

Comment: yes i have relationship in documents and user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're happy to access them through your `$client` variable in your view file then you can simply do `$client->document`.

If you want to be a bit more explicit or you change this is be an ajax response then in your controller you would have:

```
$client->load('document');
```

Or if you want to load the relationship in to a different variable you can do:

```
$document = $client->document()->first();

return view('admin.profile', compact('client', 'document'));
```

Comment: i'm try last one one error is show "Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::documents does not exist."

Comment: I'm try as" $documents = $client->document()->get(); " it's remove error but noting is show in data

Comment: @RanaRaheelTariq In that case can you show how you defined your relationship for documents.

Comment: I have three table users table, profiles table and documents table documents table have user_id and profile_id and i'm create relation in User and Profile Model like this public function document(){ return $this->hasOne('\App\Document'); } and in Document model have user and Profile relation like this public function user(){ return $this->belongsTo('App\User'); } same as define Profile function

Comment: @RanaRaheelTariq In your question it says "every Single user Have Many Documents" which I took to be a `hasMany` relationship not a `hasOne`. Since the method name is `document` and not `documents`, that is all you should need to change for my answer...I'll update it now.